# Register multiple svg icons from single svg file mat-icons

Tags: svg, angular-material, google-material-icons

This is the current icon service to register custom svg icons

```
export class IconService {
  constructor(
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  public registerIcons(): void {
    this.loadIcons(Object.values(Icons), '../assets/icons');
  }

  private loadIcons(iconKeys: string[], iconUrl: string): void {
    iconKeys.forEach((key) => {
      this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        key,
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          `${iconUrl}/${key}.svg`
        )
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Instead of loading the svg per each file, I put all the svgs into a single folder with this kinda syntax

`my-icons.svg`

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="icon_id">
  ...
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
...
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
        key,
        this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
          `${iconUrl}/my-icons.svg#${key}`
        )
      );
...
```

where each `key` is an id pointing to the `<symbol id="icon_id">...` in the `my-icons.svg` file

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what You want but You can do this:

```
this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIconSet(
      this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("icon_url.svg")
    );
```

You will use icons by id like this:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="id_of_symbol_in_icon_url_svg_file"></mat-icon>
```